# updating a db record each time i retrieve it from the db - is it a good practice?

Tags: c#, sql, database

I'm using an sql server and i have a specific table that can contain ~1million-~10 million recrdords max.

In each record i retrieve I do some checkings (i run a few simple lines of code), and then I want to mark that the records was checked in DateTime.Now;
so what i do is retrieve a record, check some stuff, run an 'update' query to set the 'last_checked_time' field to DateTime.Now, and then move to the next record.
I can then get all the records ordered by their 'last_checked_time' field (ascending), and then i can iterate over them ordered by the their check time..

Is this a good practice ? Can it still remain speedy as long as i have no more than 10 million records on that table ?

I've read somewhere that every 'update' query is actually a deletion and a creation of a new record.

I'd also like to mention that these records will be frequently retrieved by my ASP.net website ..

I was thinking of writing down the 'last_checked_time' on a local txt file/binary file,but i'm guessing it would mean implementing something that the database can already do for you.

Comment: why do you need the checked time? What exactly are you checking? Is it something that could be handled by having proper controls inteh database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend retrieving your data or a portion of the data, doing your checks on all of them and sending the updates back in transactions to let the database operate more effectively.  This would provide for fewer round trips.

As to if this is a good practice, I would say yes especially since you are using in in your queries.  Definitely, do not store the last checked time in a file and try to match up after you load your database data.  The database RDBMS is designed to effeciently handle this for you.  Don't reinvent the wheel using cubes.

Comment: Exxcept I would sent the updates back as a batch - set-based updates much faster than individual updates.

Comment: @HLGEM: You haven't really described your use-case in much detail, but you'll have to decide if you can afford to queue up several updates and send them in a batch, or if you need the lower latency provided by individual updates.

Answer (score 2):

If you need that "last checked time" value then the best, most efficient, place to hold it is on the row in the table.  It doesn't matter how many rows there are in the table, each update will affect just the row(s) you updated.

How an update is implemented is up to the DBMS, but it is not generally done by deleting and re-inserting the row.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I see no issues with it. It seems perfectly reasonable to store the last checked time in the database, especially since it might be used in queries (for example, to find records that haven't been checked in over a week).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe (just maybe) you could create a new table containing two rows: the id of the row in the first table and the checked date.

That way you wouldn't alter the original table, but depending on the usage of the data and the check date you would be forced to make a joined query which is maybe something you also don't want to do.

Answer (score 1):

It makes sense to store the 'checked time' as part of the row you're updating, rather than in a separate file or even a separate table in the database. This approach should provide optimal performance and help to maintain consistency. Solutions involving more than one table or external data stores may introduce a requirement for distributed or multi-table transactional updates that involve significant locking, which can negatively impact performance and make it much more difficult to guarantee consistency.

In general, solutions that minimize the scope of transactions and, by extension, locking, are worth striving for.  Also, simplicity itself is a useful goal.